# what is the difference between a cycle and a circuit in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory

> A cycle of a graph G, also called a circuit if the first vertex is not specified, is a subset of the edge set of G that forms a path such that the first node of the path corresponds to the last.

This is the definition of cycle in the WolframMathWorld page. I don't understand how a cycle becomes a circuit if the 1st vertex is not specified.
I thought :

a circuit is a closed walk with no repeated EDGES.
a cycle is a closed walk with no repeated edges and no repeated vertices

Answer (score 2):

In graph theory conventions unfortunately differ in different contexts and with different authors. Your definition of cycle is the usual one except that cycles are often given with a specific order of vertex, edge, vertex, ... . Circuits can then be considered to be cycles but with no specific starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Terminology aside, the important thing is that you're aware of (and can distinguish between) the following concepts:

- A sequence of vertices $(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k)$ such that $v_i v_{i+1}$ for each $i$ and $v_k v_1$ are edges of the graph.

  - Additionally, we can require the edges to be distinct...
  - ...or the vertices *and* the edges to be distinct. (Asking for the vertices but not the edges to be distinct is weird, since the only additional object it allows is the two-edge walk from $v$ to $w$ back to $v$.)
- A subgraph of the graph isomorphic to the cycle graph $C_k$ for some $k$.

All of these are occasionally called "cycles", and I would not be surprised if any of them except the last were called "circuits". You have to figure out what a cycle is from context.

MathWorld's definition "a subset of the edge set such that ..." is essentially equivalent to my last bullet point, and is useful for talking about [unicyclic graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnicyclicGraph.html), for example. (Although, if we say that cycles specify the first vertex and circuits don't, then unicyclic graphs would have to be defined as "graphs with exactly one *circuit*", showing that even MathWorld taken on its own is not entirely consistent about this usage.)